# Flag events between two reason codes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with time series data that has an event column. An 's' in the event column indicates the start of an event while 'S' denotes the end.

Some records can fall outside of s and S and they are not of interest to me.

I need to group these records into numbered events. Essentially, I need to capture the first set of records between an s and S and label them as event 1, the next set as event 2, etc.

I'm trying to do this in My SQL and can't think of the best way to do it.

```
SET @trip_num = 0;
SET @id = '';    

SELECT
    *,
    @trip_num := CASE WHEN @id = vid THEN 
                 CASE WHEN event = binary 's' THEN @trip_num + 1 ELSE @trip_num END 
                    ELSE 
                 CASE WHEN reason = binary 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                    END AS 'trip_id',
    @id := vid

FROM table
ORDER BY vid, datestamp;
```

This is how I've done it so far but the problem is that records following an 'S' and before a 's' will get counted as being part of an event.

Any ideas?

Perhaps I could add flag if the record has a timestamp later than the 'S' event within a trip and filter those out.

Comment: You've got to be joking.  Who designed a system that has such different meanings for `'s'` and `'S'`?  Immediately change the data so the end has a different value, say `'e'`.

Comment: What conditions define the "first set", the "second set", etc?

Comment: @lurker Hi Lurker, the first set is all records between the first successive s and S occurrence, the second is all records between the second successive s and S occurrence, etc. For example, the reason codes may look like s T T T b b S a a s T S so the first trip would be s T T T b b S and the second would be s T S, a's are ignored because they fall outside a s S pattern.

Comment: @GordonLinoff IKR?!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Someone who thought s and S being opposite in regular expressions was too easy to remember.